# How to loop back to multiple options if invalid option is entered?

Tags: java

I have a program that has several methods that manipulate a given string in different ways. I need to give the user a menu to select which method to perform. If an invalid option is entered it needs to give the menu and allow the user to try again. after a method is run it also needs to give the user the option to select another option or end the program. I have no problem writing the options and running the different methods, but I'm not sure how to run it again. Here is what I am working on in my test class.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class TestStringManip {
        //=================MAIN===============
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
        String input = in.nextLine();

        StringManipulation newString = new StringManipulation(input);

        String menu = newString.getMenu();
        System.out.println(menu);
        int option = in.nextInt();

        if (option == 1)
        {
            String upperCase = newString.getUpperCase(input);
            System.out.println(upperCase);
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("Error: must select options 1-5 from menu");
            System.out.println(menu);
            int option2 = in.nextInt();
        }

    }

}
```

I have tried a few new things. Here is what I have right now. It will now print the menu again, but when I select a new option it doesn't call on the method.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class TestStringManip {
        //=================MAIN===============
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
        String input = in.nextLine();

        StringManipulation newString = new StringManipulation(input);

        String menu = "\n Please select an option to perform"
                + "\n1 (1) Get all uppercase letters."
                + "\n2 (2) Get every second letter."
                + "\n3 (3) Replace vowels with _ "
                + "\n4 (4) Get a count of all vowels."
                + "\n5 (5) Get position of all vowels.";
        System.out.println(menu);
        int option = in.nextInt();


        do
        {
            if (option == 1)
            {
                newString.getUpperCase(input);
            }

            else if (option == 2)
            {
                newString.getEverySecond(input);
            }

            else
            {
                System.out.println("Error must select 1-5");
                System.out.println(menu);
                option = in.nextInt();
            }
        }while (option < 1 || option > 5);
    }

}
```

Comment: Wrap everything in a loop.

Comment: Consider creating a method that shows the menu and waits for user input and returns what they select.  Wrap the call in a loop to repeat until the user selects the "exit" option...you could also write a input method which took a range of valid options and wouldn't return until the user selected the correct one...

Answer (score 0):

```
do { // do ... while loop
    if (option == 1)
            {
                String upperCase = newString.getUpperCase(input);
                System.out.println(upperCase);
            }

            else
            {
                System.out.println("Error: must select options 1-5 from menu");
                System.out.println(menu);
                option = in.nextInt();
            }    
}   while (option < 1 || option > 5); // keep looping as long as it is less than 1 or more than 5
```

Using a do ... while loop to check if the option is within 1 - 5, note that I removed option2 variable and use/check on the variable "option" instead